# How to prevent input of numbers in a form using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

This is the part of my multi-step registration form, and it working fine.
But I want to add a number validation to the "student_name" variable, so the system will prevent the student to input the number in their name.

```
if (step === 2) {
    // Example: check if username is not empty
    var student_name = document.querySelector('#student_name').value;
    if (student_name === '') {
        isValid = false;
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Field still empty'
        });
    } else if (student_name.length < 3 || student_name.length > 30) {
        isValid = false;
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'info',
            title: 'the character must <3 or >30'
        });
    } else
        var student_email = document.querySelector('#student_email').value;
    if (student_email === '') {
        isValid = false;
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Field still empty'
        });
    } else if (!student_email.includes('@')) {
        isValid = false;
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Email must include "@"'
        });
    }
}
```

So I added this code that I got it from the ai.

```
if (/\d/.test(student_name)) {
    isValid = false;

    // Display an error message using SweetAlert
    Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Error',
        text: 'number is not allowed in student name.'
    });
}
```

So this is my code after I add that code.

```
if (step === 2) {
    // Example: check if username is not empty
    var student_name = document.querySelector('#student_name').value;
    if (student_name === '') {
        isValid = false;
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Field still empty'
        });
    } else if (student_name.length < 3 || student_name.length > 30) {
        isValid = false;
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'info',
            title: 'the character must <3 or >30'
        });
    }
    // new added code (start)
     else if (/\d/.test(student_name)) {
        isValid = false;
    
        // Display an error message using SweetAlert
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Error',
            text: 'number is not allowed in student name'
        });
    }
    // new added code (end)
     else
        var student_email = document.querySelector('#student_email').value;
    if (student_email === '') {
        isValid = false;
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Field still empty'
        });
    } else if (!student_email.includes('@')) {
        isValid = false;
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Email must include "@"'
        });
    }
}
```

But it didn't work - there is no error message.

Comment: What does the HTML form look like?

Comment: "*I want to add a number validation to the "student_name" variable*" Then where did `nama_siswa` come from? It's not defined anywhere. You should be getting an error that you're accessing an undeclared variable.

Comment: A decent Form validation should not be doen with JavaScript (unless Node.js) but by the build in validation method of using the `required` attribute so that the form can auto-validate itself!

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask something more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the mistake lies in the variable name nama_siswa.

Instead you should be using the student_name as the variable to test with the regex /d representing a digit from 0 to 9.

So your code should look like this:

```
// new added code (start)
 else if (/\d/.test(student_name)) {
    isValid = false;

    // Display an error message using SweetAlert
    Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Error',
        text: 'number is not allowed in student name'
    });
}
// new added code (end)
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML forms validate themself.

To valdiate if a name has a length of 3-30 charters you can add the `minlength="3"` and `maxlength="30"` attribtues.

Emails can be validated if the input has the `type="email"` attribtue.

All you need to do is to add the `required` attribute to the inputs and it will even throw a localized error message that is depending on the users system language:

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" minlength="3" maxlength="30" required>
  
  <br>
  
  <label for="email">E-Mail:</label>
  <input type="email" required>
  
  <br><br>
  
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PS: You should not ask an AI to program for you. An AI will just execute your prompt and provide an answer based on that. An AI will **not** tell you if you ask the wrong question in the first place (XY-Issue).

Answer (score 1):

I think Alain Ghawi is correct that your problem is that the regex checks a variable called `nama_siswa` instead of `student_name`. However, I want to add that you can run into a lot of other problems aside from numbers in the name field.

For example, Unicode has an array of numerical characters that aren't caught by \d. In some cases, you can use \p{n} to match all Unicode characters with the "numerical" property, but this does not seem to be well implemented yet in browsers. Some workarounds can be found here: [How can I use Unicode-aware regular expressions in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/how-can-i-use-unicode-aware-regular-expressions-in-javascript)

If you know the locality of your users and can expect them to use Roman-alphabet-based languages, then it might be easier to restrict entry to a set of allowed characters. However, you should be permissive enough to allow variants like é and ñ. I highly recommend the program RegexBuddy for testing your regexp against possible names.

Lastly, I highly recommend doing a secondary check on the backend. If bad characters can mess up your other scripts, then you cannot rely on browser-based verification alone. The server needs to check the entered data and make sure that it conforms before it is saved.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the build-in form validation. For the student name a min and max length, and maybe a pattern of some kind.

For displaying the alert you can use the invalid event that is fired when something in the form is not valid.

The form will only submit if the entire form is valid.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  swal({
    title: e.target.title,
    icon: "error",
  });
}, true);

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('submitting...');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js" integrity="sha512-AA1Bzp5Q0K1KanKKmvN/4d3IRKVlv9PYgwFPvm32nPO6QS8yH1HO7LbgB1pgiOxPtfeg5zEn2ba64MUcqJx6CA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<form name="form01">
  <label>Student name:<input type="text" name="student_name" minlength="3"
    maxlength="30" pattern="[^\d]+"
    title="Student name must be between 3 and 30 characters and no digits"
    required></label>
  <label>Student email:<input type="email" name="student_email"
  title="The email must be a valid email address" required></label>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```